# where is the texture paint image hiding?

Tags: python, scripting, texture-painting

How can I extract the Image(ID) I paint on from Material(ID) of the object? I've tried:

```
bpy.data.materials['Material'].texture_slots[:]
```

But I can see only the textures I use for texture painting, that I switch between, while painting. I've also tried every other field with "texture" in it, without success (they mostly reference the textures in the slots). Consequently, I don't know how to decide, given a material, whether it uses a painted texture and which painted texture it uses.

Side question: how does blender know, that the texture I paint on, is the texture that should be applied to the faces, the material is assigned to? Painting a texture and applying it are 2 different things. One could easily paint a texture, but have another texture applied (i.e. not the one painted on). Yet, If I set a light property and switch into Texture Viewport Shading, I see the texture I am painting on.